# Limit definition of curvature and torsion

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given two point, $P$ and $Q$, lying on a curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$, curvature at $P$ can be defined via limit $$\kappa (P) = \lim_{Q \to P} \sqrt{\frac{24 (s(P,Q) - d(P,Q))}{s(P,Q)^3}},$$ where $s(P,Q)$ is the arc length of the curve $\gamma$ between the points $P$ and $Q$, and $d(P,Q)$ is the length of a line segment from $P$ to $Q$.

Is there a similar geometrical definition of torsion at $P$?

Comment: Can you give a proof for the formula ?

Comment: @HKLee Just use Taylor expansion, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas#Taylor_expansion

Comment: 24 is very curious to me (though I'm a layman to DG.

Comment: @ LBO me too; replace 4! by 3!

Comment: @Narasimham: our formulae agree if you take into account that you have half-distances, while I have the real distances.

Comment: I changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example given is for curvature in the osculation plane rotation $\theta$ :

Arc $ s  = 2 R \theta $ in $ \mathbb R^2$

Direct Euclidean  distance  $ d = 2 R \sin \theta$

Series approximation for third order

$$ s/R = 2 \theta;\, d/R= 2 \sin \theta \approx 2(\theta - \theta^3/3!)= 2(s/2R- (s/R)^3/8\cdot3!) $$

$$ d \approx  s - s^3/(24 R^2 )$$

$$ \frac1R = \kappa \approx \sqrt  \frac{ 24 (s-d)}{s^3}$$

the same as your result. You see that we dealt with infinitesmal lengths ( that later on tend to zero) as small finite lengths that can be sketched to visible proportions. [Incidentally I read somewhere it was similarly handled by Leibnitz during earliest stages of calculus].

We used $ t' = \kappa\, n $ in Frenet-Serret frame

Similarly we can now develop

$$ b'= \tau \,n  $$

in the plane of normals (principal and bi- normal)

Let the instantaneous radius of torsion be $\rho$, we have torsion

$$ \tau = \frac{d \theta }{ds} = \frac{\sin \psi }{\rho} $$

Length $ dl $ extends by twisting to $ ds$ in normal plane so that $ \cos \psi = dl/ds$

$$ \sin \psi \approx 1 - ( dl /ds)^2/ 2 ;\,\, \tau = \frac{1 - ( dl /ds)^2/ 2 }{\rho} $$

You can write/define using your nomenclature

$$ ds = s(P,Q), dl = d(P,Q). $$

[image: Torsion]

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: rotation of normal vector in normal  (N-B) plane, basic angle of torsion

Comment: Ok, great, thanks! I will accept your answer. Can you please provide some further literature on the subject?

Comment: Can add one sketch to show radius, twist etc. If the arc is going on line of curvature there is no twist etc..

Comment: That would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: The above is almost fundamental. Curvature is defined as rate of rotation change in osculating, and torsion in normal/bi-normal planes per unit length. In engineering mechanics one defines bending moment and torque proportional to these, with constants of proportionality being EI & GJ.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer But from the following I believe that torsion can not be obtained from arc length and distance, since torsion is related with curvature)

If $\alpha$ has a unit speed, then we have $$ t:=\alpha',\ n'=-kt
+\tau b,\ b'=-\tau n $$

Consider a surface $$ f(u,v)=u b(v) + \alpha (v) $$ That is unit
normal field is $-n$ so that we have first and second fundamental
forms : $$ E=1,\ F=0, G=1
$$
$$ e=0,\ f=\tau,\ g=k $$

Then we have a Gaussian curvature
$$ K=-\tau^2
$$

(Note that there exists an intrinsic definition of $K$ : $
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0 } 3\frac{2\pi r-C(r)}{\pi r^3} $ where $C(r)$
is a length of geodesic sphere of radius $r$)

Similarly $$  f(u,v)=u n(v) + \alpha (v) $$ Here unit normal field
is $-b$ Then we have a Gaussian curvature $$ K=\frac{-\tau^2
}{(1-k)^2 + \tau^2 }
$$